# How to resolve "cannot merge new index 65536 into a non-jumbo instruction!" in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I when i'm launching the app, my Eclipse IDE console shows the following error/warning

```
[2015-11-07 12:08:56 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 65536 into a non-jumbo instruction!
[2015-11-07 12:08:56 - <AppName>] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 65536 into a non-jumbo instruction!
```

can any please give the clear solution for this, may of them gave solution for Android Studio, I tried the following

```
 1. Added dex.force.jumbo=true as very firstl ine in my project.properties file
 2. Enabled proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Can any one please provide the solution for ECLIPSE IDE. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You are hitting the 65535 method Dex limit.

This is becoming more and more common as developers pull in things like the Android support library.

Two things I would suggest:

First, migrate your app to Android Studio!  This is probably not what you want to hear, but Google is dropping support for the Eclipse ADT plugin.

Second, add multidex support as outlined in the developer documentation here: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

I understand the reluctance developers may have to making the switch from Eclipse to Android Studio.  However, if you don't, you'll quickly be left behind.  All the latest tooling is centered around Gradle now.

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately now this point i can't able to switch the IDE, because my app having more reference library

Comment: @Aerrow: I certainly understand sometimes you are stuck with the dev environment you have.  Have you thought about using proguard to help strip things down?

Comment: @ Michael Krause: Can you please provide any documentation/video tutorials reg how to enable prograud, because i refered some links, they simple uncomment this line #proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt in properties file, may i know is this a common for all else i need to replace the current application path